# Execution order of DoubleClick Command and DoubleClick Event Handler

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, command

I want to separate UI from program logic and therefore introduce a DoubleClick Command for a DataGridRow. I managed to enable my DataGrid to execute Commands when a row is double clicked. In xaml, I can now use my DataGrid like this:

```
<DataGrid h:Commands.DataGridRowDoubleClickCommand="{Binding SomeCommand}">
    ...
</DataGrid>
```

The technique is similar [to this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/wpf/thread/632ea875-a5b8-4d47-85b3-b30f28e0b827).

Double clicking a row now executes the command. Now, I want to have an event handler for a DataGridRow that opens a new Window via `ShowDialog()`.

Problem now: the event handler is executed before the command. Is there any way to change the order of Handlers in events like MouseDoubleClick?

Comment: Why do you split the doubleclick logic for one and the same control? Is there any necessity?

Comment: In the event handler, I just want to open a new window. This is just ui logic. In the command, ViewModels should be modified, so the window can use them as DataContext later.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion opening a dialog with warning / info / data is part of the program logic. Manipulating the ui in an event handler is UI logic, but not showing informations.